# Can I have dynamic custom variables in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm basically trying to create a variable in a document, let's say the name of a person, so that I can change the value in a single place and it updates through the whole document.

I've been reading about **Fields** and about a **DOCVARIABLE**, but I can't find where to edit the value (right clic didn't show an "edit" option). I'm using Word 2011 for Mac (that's what we have at work right now) so I'm wondering whether this version of Word is just not intuitive, or I cannot have variables like that in Word and I'm misinterpreting the documentation.

This is what I intend to do:

```
Hello, my name is PERSON_NAME, I have PERSON_AGE years old.
```

You get the idea.

**PS:** We actually want to modify the variables' values from our app, rather than from Word itself, kind of like injecting values to a `.*docx` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is called **custom document property**

You can create and edit them by:

- go to File tab
- select properties - advanced properties
- go to custom tab

Once done, you can insert it:

- insert tab - quick parts - field
- from categories select document information
- in field names select DocProperty
- select your property in property list
- press ok

You can find a more detailed description e.g. [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/217329/how-to-create-custom-properties-in-a-word-document/)

Comment: Hmm will it work if I need a more complex estructure, like a table?

Comment: Do you mean storing a whole table in a custom property? No, it won't work,